# Why the threads msg are coming in reverse order?

Tags: linux, pthreads

When I run this code, I get the thread messages exactly in reverse order. If I create thread A and B, the msg for A should come first and then B. Similarly, If I create an array of 10 threads the msg should print in the sequence. If any synchronization issue was there, then the msg should not show the same reverse behavior in all the case.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
/* Required for thread APIs */
#include <pthread.h>

#define NTHREADS        10
int counter = 0;
pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

void *print_thread_msg(void *ptr){
        char *message;
        printf("Thread number %ld\n", pthread_self());
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
        counter++;
        printf("Counter value: %d\n",counter);
        message = (char *) ptr;
        printf("%s \n",message);
        sleep(1);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
        message = (char *) ptr;
        printf("%s \n",message);
}

int main (void){
        pthread_t threadA, threadB;
        pthread_t thread_id[NTHREADS];

        int i,j;

        char *msgA = "I am thread A";
        char *msgB = "I am thread B";

        pthread_create(&threadA, NULL, print_thread_msg, (void *)msgA);
        pthread_create(&threadB, NULL, print_thread_msg, (void *)msgB);

        for(i=0; i<NTHREADS; i++)
               pthread_create(&thread_id[i], NULL, print_thread_msg, (void *)"print_thread_msg");

        pthread_join(threadA, NULL);
        pthread_join(threadB, NULL);

        for(j=0; j < NTHREADS; j++)
                pthread_join(thread_id[j], NULL);

        printf(" Finally Counter Value : %d\n",counter);

        exit(0);
}
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong here.  This is the expected behavior because threads are indeterminate and you are at the mercy of the scheduler.  You can't predict when they will run or the order. When I ran your pgm 5 of your ten "print_thread_msg" threads ran before either A or B.  It could be different on every run.

Comment: I think you are right. when I run the same program on other system, it prints correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Your code runs correctly for me. I tried with 3 threads. It always starts with thread A and the rest os the threads follow randomly. Did you try running the code in some other system?

Comment: Yes I did try it on other system and it prints in correct order but I still can't figure out, why in reverse order. This can be random print. Even if I keep on adding new thread, the last one comes first.